# Remove bottom padding from textarea, and also disable "return" key

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I want to style a textarea to look like a default, one-line text input... a textarea which also resizes vertically (height-wise) as the user inputs characters. I have the foundation for this figured out, using the [autosize](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize) plugin, as seen at the below JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9aSm2

```
$(function(){
    $('.animated').autosize();
});
```

What I cannot figure out is how to get rid of the extra textarea bottom padding below the placeholder text ("Enter the required information"), to disappear. This bottom padding is causing the textarea to appear to have two rows. I only want a row to be visible if there is text for it to contain. So, no bottom padding at any time, nor as the textarea grows.

Also, is there any way to disable the "return" key? This way the textarea behaves more like a one-line text input field.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your `autosize` plugin use `append` property to remove extra bottom space, by default it is

`append:'\n'`

change to this

```
$('.animated').autosize({append: '',});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9aSm2/7/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but, I am [still seeing the padding](http://www.berklie.com/appel/Chrome001.jpg) even with the new code. (Chrome 35.0.1916.114)